# How to represent a flat graph in Java Spark using Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, graph, apache-spark-dataset

Given a Dataset with two columns such as:

```
FatherNode, ChildNode
A, B
A, C
B, D
B, F
C, G
H, I
H, L
M, I
M, B
F, J
Z, K
```

I want to build a new Dataset that represents a *Flat Graph*, i.e. a representation of the all possible destinations of each node, so, in this example, the new Dataset should be:

```
Node, PossibleDestinations
A, [B, C, D, F, J]
B, [D, F, J]
C, [G]
H, [I, L]
M, [I, B, D, F, J]
F, [J]
Z, [K]
```

For example, **A** could reach **B**, **C**, **D**, **F** and **J**: doesn't matter the path.

My simple code (implemented) is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

public class FlatGraph {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Flat Graph").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> csvData = spark.read().option("header", "true").csv("data.csv").cache();
        csvData.show();
        Dataset<Row> flatGraph = [...]; // What operations could be performed here?
        flatGraph.show();
        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html). Pure dataframe operations are not best suited for graph computations. See also the [java docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/graphx/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response, but we cannot use external libraries due to a proxy that blocks Maven unauthorized libraries. :(

Comment: GraphX is part of Spark, not a third-party library.

Comment: Why when I add `import org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph;`I get `package org.apache.spark.graphx does not exist`? However I have no problems to add `import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;` or others.

Comment: @kitsune spark version?

Comment: org.apache.spark, spark-sql_2.12, version: 3.0.1

Comment: however we solved successfully requiring dependency in `build.gradle`, now we are able to use GraphX, thanks